# iOS: multiline uilabel only shows one line with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

The code below, I think should result iin a multiline label followed by a button, however, after layout there is only a single line of the label showing up. While I could put an explicit height in the vertical layout that would defeat the purpose. Any ideas about what other constraints I should apply?

```
UILabel *lbExplain = [[UILabel alloc] init];
lbExplain.text = @"The Sync process allows you to synchronize your library between different devices. By clicking on the button below you can find other devices to sync with. The other device also has to be running this applicaton.";
lbExplain.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
lbExplain.numberOfLines = 0;
lbExplain.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

UIButton *btnPartner = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btnPartner setTitle:@"Look for Partners" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnPartner addTarget:self action:@selector(findPartners:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btnPartner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.view addSubview:lbExplain];
[self.view addSubview:btnPartner];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[lbExplain]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(lbExplain)]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[lbExplain]-[btnPartner]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(lbExplain, btnPartner)]];
```

Comment: What happens if you call `-sizeToFit` on the label?

Comment: I can't see off hand what's missing. If you do basically the same thing in IB it works fine.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Add the line:

```
lbExplain.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 280;
```

This must be something that is done automatically in IB, since the label expands properly if you set it up there. The number you pass it does seem to matter some in how it expands vertically, but it doesn't override the constraints you set for the width.

**After Edit:**

It works better if I add that line in updateViewConstraints, and relate the number to the view's bounds. This way it adjusts properly on rotation.

```
-(void)updateViewConstraints {
    [super updateViewConstraints];
    lbExplain.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width - 40;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that actually works although I'm kind of mystified as to why? 280 just seems like a magic number but it works for both the iPad and iphone (the ipad of course being way wider than 280).

Comment: Does it really work on iPad, even if you rotate? 280 is just 320 minus the two 20 point spaces (default) to the sides that you set. I notice that on rotation on the iPhone, the label ends up with whitespace above and below the text.

Comment: If does mostly work on the iPad. Both ipad and iphone seem to basically size the thing in what the height would be for a portrait screen so they leave extra space above and below in the wider landscape views. Not ideal, but better than the clipped text.

Comment: Sorry missed your edit before the last response. You're right that is more consistent. Also had to add it to "didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation" in order for it to change with the orientation. It isn't exactly smooth, but functional.

Comment: @ckh, hmm.... I don't know why you had to add it to "didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation", I didn't do that, and it adjusted perfectly to the rotation. Did you add exactly the same thing I posted?

Comment: Replaced the implementation of updateViewConstraints with - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    self.explaination.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width - 40;
}
Which worked for me, updateViewConstraints wasn't called on rotation but the layout subviews is.

Comment: @ckh, that's strange, updateViewConstraints is called at startup and on every rotation for me.

Comment: It does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` is not set. As a result, the text is not constrained by any width and, as such, it does not wrap to the next line.

I've found that the easiest way to use a multiline `UILabel` with Autolayout is to create a subclass:

```
@interface MyMultilineLabel : UILabel

@end


@implementation MyMultilineLabel

- (void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    [super setBounds:bounds];
    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(bounds);
    if (self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth != width) {
        self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = width;
    }
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        self.numberOfLines = 0;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you don't have ambiguous layout ?

you can make a test in your code like

```
if ([self.view hasAmbiguousLayout]) {
    NSLog(@"ambiguous");
}
```

or make pause on the simulator or test device and type in console :

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]
```

if so, you might wanna try to make your contraints a bit more explicit like (at first sight, height is ambiguous):

```
@"V:|-[lbExplain]-[btnPartner]-|"
```

or

```
@"V:|-[lbExplain(==300)]-[btnPartner(==200)]"
```

here is the documentation to the visual format language :

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/formatLanguage.html

Comment: The OP's constraints are not ambiguous, because labels and buttons have an intrinsic height. As for your second suggestion, that's what he's trying to avoid (setting an explicit height).

Comment: A `UILabel` only has an intrinsic size when it is one line.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where a multiline label in a UITableViewCell, positioned with AutoLayout, wouldn't expand itself.

It was inside a UITableView handling sizes 'automatically' with *UITableViewAutomaticDimension* and *estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath* method. (I think it may be the source of the problem)

I figured out this problem by calling :

```
[cell layoutIfNeeded]
```

in the *cellForRowAtIndexPath* method, just before returning the cell.

And it worked like a charm !