# Subview greater than its superview in ios / objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, storyboard

I have a view of limited width, lets say it 100.

I have multiple labels of same width inside that view and its text is centre aligned. So that text seems to be center aligned always.

Problem is when I got long text label it shows ellipses at the end of the text but I want to show whole text in one time while keeping superview width unchanged. Is it possible to attain this? If not then show how can I wrap that text if it is larger than its width. I'm new to IOS programming.

Comment: Try setting label's numberOfLines property to "0" either programmatically or in story board :) What it will do is it will show your text in multiple lines :) That should solve your issue as you will be able to show the text as well its width will not be more than its parent :)

Comment: That means it is not possible to increase the width of label :(

Comment: its your own requirement right, that width of the parent should not increse ??

Comment: set number of line 0 and wordwrap in line break mode

Comment: I dont want to increase the width of view, but if it is possible to increase the width of label more than its parent view. Wait let me see if I can make margin in negative numbers

Comment: by the way line number to 0 is working gud for me

Comment: adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth I saw this property, is there any way to assign it using storyboard or i have to assign this in code ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with UILabel and autolayout. If you using it - check this answer: [iOS: multiline uilabel only shows one line with autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058108/ios-multiline-uilabel-only-shows-one-line-with-autolayout)

Also, check actual size of label and insure clipsToBound of superview is set to NO.